# SpringUI cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, vaadin

Following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qUBt8k4pQgQ&t=1642s) tutorial I'm trying to setup a `Maven` project with `Spring-boot` and `Vaadin`.

I'm getting `SpringUI cannot be resolved to a type` error on the `@SpringUI` annotation.

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>8.0.5</vaadin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

**DemoApplication.java:**

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**TodoUI.java:**

```
package com.example.demo;

import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;
import com.vaadin.spring.annotation.SpringUI;

@SpringUI(path = "/myPath") // SpringUI cannot be resolved to a type | WHY?
public class TodoUI extends UI {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1463774427806228298L;

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {

    }

}
```

**What am I doing wrong here?**

Comment: You don't seem to import `SpringUI`. Try adding `import com.vaadin.spring.annotation.SpringUI` to TodoUI.java

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy It's not the `import`. Same error occurs on the `import` if I do it manually. Interestingly enough `Intellisense` can find the `com.vaadin.spring.annotation` but not the `class` it self.

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy Edited the `import`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked your source code, and everything looks fine, so possible some configurations errors or something like that.

But, to get working project, you can download from video ready project on github: https://github.com/vaadin-marcus/spring-boot-todo and import it. And can compare, where is your error.

Comment: Thank you. The project worked, then I copied the pom into my project and it worked. Then I poked around a bit and found that it was the Vaadin version(8.0.5), after I changed it to an older one(8.0.1) the issue was solved. I don't understand the exact reason that version 8.0.5 didn't work though.

Comment: You really, really shouldn't use a version as ancient as 8.0.5, let alone 8.0.1. The last free version of Vaadin 8 is 8.15.0, you should use that.

Answer (score 0):

The question is about Vaadin 8, but you will also get this error when doing the tutorial with Vaadin 10 and 11. Seems like the reason for that is that [@SpringUI was replaced by @UIScope in Vaadin 10 and higher](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17299898/springboot-application-springui-in-vaadin-version-11-not-available).

Since the tutorial linked is therefore out of date, I would recommend [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bxy2JgqqKDU) as an up to date alternative.